# Object is not getting stored in Redis cache

Tags: spring-boot, redis

I have a class User as following:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@RedisHash("loggedInUser")
public class User implements Serializable {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1625655374442156393L;
    @Id
    private Long userId;
    private String username;
    private String role;

}
```

while logging in i save the object by `repository.save()` but on fetching data from redis through `keys *` I can't find loggedInUser in it. The repository I'm using is:

```
@Repository
public interface AppAuthenticationRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    LoggedInUser findByUsername(String username);
    LoggedInUser deleteByUsername(String username);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the appropriate configuration classes set up? For example:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableRedisRepositories
public class RedisConfig {

  @Bean
  public RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
    return new JedisConnectionFactory();
  }

  @Bean
  public RedisTemplate<?, ?> redisTemplate() {
    RedisTemplate<byte[], byte[]> template = new RedisTemplate<byte[], byte[]>();
    return template;
  }
}
```

Once you have your Redis configuration setup, your repository can be defined as so:

```java
@Repository
public interface AppAuthenticationRepository extends CrudRepository<LoggedInUser, Long> {
    LoggedInUser findByUsername(String username);
    LoggedInUser deleteByUsername(String username);
}
```

You also have `JpaRepository<User, Long>`, but return `LoggedInUser`. I'd give `CrudRepository<LoggedInUser, Long>` a try.

The [Spring Data Redis documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-redis/docs/current/reference/html/#redis.repositories.usage) has a good usage example that should help as well.

Comment: Yes. It turns out i was looking at the wrong DB. My bad but thanks.